# Help with jellyfish species identification

Tags: species-identification, zoology, marine-biology, invertebrates

Our research group (Evolutionary Genetics Group, University of Zurich) has received a letter from a special needs child who has kindly asked us to identify three jellyfish species.

Unfortunately, the letter does not include anything else except three rather low quality cutouts from what I assume is a childrens book. Nobody in our lab has any knowledge about jellyfish taxonomy so any help is greatly appreciated.

[image: cutout 1]
[image: cutout 2]
[image: cutout 3]

Comment: https://jellywatch.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be warned that these are just best guesses - as you said yourself, these aren't great images for identification as they appear to be simple drawings:

1) this looks a lot like *Aurelia aurita* - though the lack of any internal patterning in the drawing makes me think perhaps otherwise.
[image: Aurelia Aurita]
[image: Aurelia Aurita 2]

image source: https://www.leisurepro.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/shutterstock_272438348.jpg, https://holidays-majorca.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/Aurelia-Aurita-S-300x225.jpg

2) possibly a *Turritopsis dohrnii or nutricala* - if so then this is the 'immortal' jellyfish. shape of bell is correct and the lappets seem reasonably close, it's just the internal structures that I'm not sure about.
[image: Turritopsis dohrnii]

image source: https://www.cairnsholidayspecialists.com.au/shared_resources/media/irukandji-jellyfish-in-far-north-18836_400x322.jpg

3) Very unsure about this one, but potentially a *Atolla wyvillei*? definitely has some visual features in common and I can't find anything else that's similar. I can also see how an artist would derive that image from this species.
[image: Atolla manubrium]
[image: Atolla Manubrium 2]

Image source: https://www.mindenpictures.com/cache/pcache2/90194947.jpg, https://c8.alamy.com/comp/E45A4H/deepsea-medusa-jellyfish-atolla-manubrium-gulf-of-maine-atlantic-E45A4H.jpg

I hope these at least give a starting point and are of some help, I think the nature of those images will make it hard to get many better answers. Good luck!!

Comment: Thank you very much! I did get in touch with Lisa Gershwin via email as well. Species ID I got from her are: 1: Aequorea victoria, 2: Polyorchis penicillatus, 3: Atolla wyvillei. But I think based on the photo quality one cannot be 100% sure. In any case, I'm sure the kid will be excited and I will send him the full list with all species proposed.

Comment: Well, I defer to her better judgment! They certainly fit better than my ones... I'm chuffed to bits that I got Atolla wyvillei right though!

Comment: -1. Looks like your 1st 2 are wrong. Good job on the third. (You can [edit] if you think you can improve your answer)